# FFServer ошибка swf

Tags: ffmpeg

Делаю стрим с веб-камеры через ffserver в swf типе, как только пытаюсь получить стрим, вижу такую ошибку

Invalid (too large) frame rate 1000000/1

Конфиг ниже

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxClients 150
MaxBandwidth 50000
CustomLog /var/log/ffserver-access.log

<Feed webcam.ffm>
    File /tmp/webcam.ffm
</Feed>

<Stream webcam.swf>
    Feed webcam.ffm
    Format swf
    VideoFrameRate 2
    VideoIntraOnly
    NoAudio
</Stream>

<Stream index.html>
   Format status
</Stream>
```